# How to mock service with Mockito?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have a spring shell application. I need to test commands. My command:

```
@Autowired
private RemoteService remoteService;

@ShellMethod
public String list(){
    List<String> items= remoteService.getAll();
    return items.toString();
}
```

My test:

```
@Test
public void listCommandTest(){
    RemoteService remoteService=mock(RemoteService.class);
    when(remoteService.getAll()).thenReturn(new ArrayList<>());

    shell.evaluate(()->"list");

    verify(remoteConfigService).getAll();
}
```

I don't need to call real method getAll() of RemoteService, but it is called. How to fix it?

Comment: what is the structure of actual class, while testing you should be injecting mocks in your actual class and call the method that you are testing explicity. I think `shell.evaluate(()->"list")` is causing issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you inject the mocked service into the code under test?

There are two options:

1) Inject the mocked service via a constructor

```
@Autowired
public ShellCommands(RemoteService remoteService) {
    this.remoteService = remoteService;
}
```

2) Create a Test Configuration

```
@Configuration
public class TestConfiguration {
    @Bean
    RemoteService remoteService() {
        RemoteService remoteService=mock(RemoteService.class);
        when(remoteService.getAll()).thenReturn(new ArrayList<>());
        return remoteService;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are mocking the `when(remoteService.getAll(anyString()))` method, and you are calling the `getAll()`.

Replace `when(remoteService.getAll(anyString()))` by `when(remoteService.getAll())`

Comment: sorry, it was my mistake while creating a question. I don't use anyString() in real code